# Why can't I call logout directly in a button submit instead of doing the post to /identity/account/logout

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

In the ASP.NET Core Identity library I understand why it needs a POST to /identity/account/logout instead of a GET. But would it be ok to handle it as a (using DevExpress):

```
<DxButton Text="Log Off" RenderStyle="@ButtonRenderStyle.Secondary" Click="LogOut"></DxButton>

@code {
    private void LogOut()
    {
         SignInManager.SignOutAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

This strikes me as a lot simpler and direct. Is there a downside to this approach?